# Заполнение QTableWidget от CSV

Tags: c++, qt, csv

Нужно пропарсить `csv` файл и вывести его в `TableWidget`. Может быть есть у кого то рабочий варик?

То что снизу не работает, он ругается на момент считывания столбцов и строк, но тут я так понимаю надо бахнуть ограничитель на `;`.
Но если убрать эту строку и поставить значения столбцов и строк самому он уже начинает ругаться на цикл, словно ничего в файле нет. Может быть надо какие то манипуляции в самом файле делать? Спасибо!

```
QFile file("save.csv"); 
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) 
    { 
        QDataStream stream(&file);
        qint32 row, column; 
        stream >> row >> column; 

        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(row); 
        ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(column); 
        for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) 
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) 
                ui->tableWidget->item(i,j)->read(stream); 
            file.close(); 
    }
```

Comment: Посмотрите как тут считывается из csv: https://evileg.com/ru/post/158/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагая что памяти как у дурака фантиков и/или CSV не особо большой, можно немного по хамски, но быстро:

```
QFile f("save.csv");
f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray data = f.readAll();f.close();
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(data.split('\n').count());
int i=0;int j=0;
foreach (QByteArray line, data.split('\n')){ //Попилить весь ввод на строки
    j=0;
    int x=line.split(';').count();
    if(x>ui->tableWidget->columnCount())
        ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(x);
    foreach (QByteArray cell, line.split(';')){ // попилить строку разделителем ";"
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,j,new QTableWidgetItem(QString(cell)));
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```